# Current revision svn of folder with command line

Tags: svn

I am want to get the current revision of folder.I am use this code :

"svn info %CD%\trunk | grep "Revision:" >>Revision UseToBuild.txt"

But i alway get the latest revision. Not the current revision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svn log instead.
For instance,

```
#!/bin/bash
rev=( $(svn log -l 1 target | awk '/^r[0-9]+/ {sub(/r/,"",$1); print $1}') )
```

`rev`contains the last revision that target was updated.